# Basic Ruby question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I'm not a developer but I need to install ruby tools from time to time. Can someone please explain in simple words the following terms:

- ruby-on-rails
- bundler
- rubygems & gems

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you a sysadmin for people who use Ruby tools, or do you use the tools yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) (or just Rails for short) is a web development framework written in the Ruby language. It's basically just a set of tools and standards that allow you to create websites easier and faster.

[Ruby Gems](https://rubygems.org/) (or just gems for short) are plugins, extensions, libraries, etc. for Ruby. Some are specifically created for Rails and even Rails itself is actually a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails).

[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) handles installing and using the right gems for Ruby projects (like Rails). It examines all of your project's gem dependencies and the dependencies of their dependencies and determines an exact list of gems and correct gem versions that will be available to your project. Bundler is also, itself a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler).

If you've had some Linux experience, you could say that Rails is like Gnome, gems are like debs or rpms and Bundler is like apt or yum.

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby on Rails:** 
Ruby on Rails is a web development framework written in Ruby programming language.
It is the most powerful and popular tool for building dynamic web applications.

**Bundler:**
Once we create a new Rails application,we use Bundler to install and include the gems needed by the app.The rails command for Bundler is "bundle install".

**Rubygems & gem:**
RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and libraries, a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems, and a server for distributing them
Each gem has a name, version, and platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a window user you can download everything

```
Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.1
Bundler
Git
Sqlite
TinyTDS
SQL Server Support
DevKit
```

from this [link](http://railsinstaller.org/en)

Comment: This doesn't seem to an answer to OP's question - OP asked for explanation, not for link to software installer.

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby on Rails**

Ruby is a language. Rails is a Model-View-Controller framework written in Ruby. Rails follows a software design paradigm of convention over configuration but its defaults can be changed. Once you know the convention, the idea is that it helps prevent having to write a lot of code since there's a place for all of the code which removes a lot of guesswork and looking at understanding new rails code becomes more straightforward.

**Ruby Gems**

You can think of these as plugins that extend the functionality of the Rails application. These 'gem' has their own dependencies. When you execute 'gem list', you can see which version of gems are installed for the 'gemset' you're in. You can create gemsets to keep the list of gems per application separate for each application, in combination of using RVM (ruby version manager) or similar.

**Bundler**

Bundler is used in any Ruby applications (including Rails apps) to keep versions of gems consistent for that application. There are a few things you'll need when using Bundler. You'll need to install the bundler gem into your project, you'll need a Gemfile which contains a list of gems you'd like installed for that application and you'll need to execute the 'bundle install' command. Once you run bundle install, it will look at the source host from your Gemfile to determine where it should download the gems. The gems will be installed in your GEM PATHS directory. (cd to your project folder and execute gem env to find out where your gems are). 'bundle install' will download the gems you don't already have installed and place them into your GEM PATHS directory. Based on whatever version of gems is installed, a Gemfile.lock file will be produced. This contains the list of gems and actual versions that are used in your project. Be sure to commit this file into source control. Sometimes you'll have gem dependency issues which you'll need to resolve and sometimes you may have the same gems but different versions of it downloaded. You may have to delete versions you don't want. 'gem list' will tell you which versions of gems you have installed.

Gems may be set up as 'Rails Engines' which you can think of rails applications to be used within your rails application but are namespaced out so essentially Rails Engines can be organized and coded by different people and they are quite modular especially since they are namespaced.

Answer (score 0):

- ruby-on-rails

Ruby is the programming language. Rails is a framework, written in the Ruby language.

- bundler

This manages gems (libraries of pre-written code for you to use). If you are using the Rails framework, and you add a gem to the Gemfile (one of the files in this framework), you will need to run `bundle` (shortcut for `bundle install`) in the console in order to install these libraries (so you may use them)

- rubygems & gems

Pre-written code/cool stuff you will be able to "just use", rather than trying to figure out how to do A, B, C...there is probably a gem already written that does those things! :)